# Exception when move assignment operator is used on a r-value

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, vulkan

I get a very strange crash (in debug mode only) when using the move assignment operator with a r-value:

Cleaning and recompiling the code in debug mode does not help. The crash occurs before VulkanBuffer::operator=() is called.

```
// ok
//VulkanBuffer myBuffer(logicalDevice, bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT, VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE);
//buffer_ = std::move(myBuffer);

// ok
//VulkanBuffer myBuffer = VulkanBuffer(logicalDevice, bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT, VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE);
//buffer_ = std::move(myBuffer);

// crash in debug mode, release mode works fine
//buffer_ = std::move( VulkanBuffer(logicalDevice, bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT, VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE) );

// crash in debug mode, release mode works fine
buffer_ = VulkanBuffer(logicalDevice, bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT, VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

I get this exception:

Exception thrown at 0x0000000059F95E35 (nvoglv64.dll) in Vulkan.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

This exception occurs in the VulkanBuffer non-default constructor

Can anyone shed some light on this? It seems to me that the code should be equivalent.

The actual code is as below:

Declaration of VulkanBuffer

```
#pragma once

#include "VulkanLogicalDevice.h"
#include "Vertex.h"

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class VulkanCommandPool;

class VulkanBuffer
{
public:
    VulkanBuffer();
    VulkanBuffer(const std::shared_ptr<VulkanLogicalDevice>& logicalDevice, VkDeviceSize deviceSizeInbytes, VkBufferUsageFlags bufferUsageFlags, VkSharingMode sharingMode);
    ~VulkanBuffer();
    VulkanBuffer(const VulkanBuffer &rhs) = delete;
    VulkanBuffer & operator=(const VulkanBuffer &rhs) = delete;
    VulkanBuffer(VulkanBuffer &&rhs) = delete;
    VulkanBuffer & operator=(VulkanBuffer &&rhs);

    VkBuffer & handle() { return buffer_; }
    const VkBuffer & handle() const { return buffer_; }
    const VkBufferCreateInfo & getBufferInfo() const { return createInfo_; }
    void copyDataFrom(const VulkanBuffer & rhs, const VulkanCommandPool &commandPool, VkDeviceSize dataSizeInBytes);

    friend void swap(VulkanBuffer &lhs, VulkanBuffer &rhs);

private:
    std::shared_ptr<VulkanLogicalDevice> logicalDevice_;
    VkBufferCreateInfo createInfo_;
    VkBuffer buffer_;
};
```

Definition of VulkanBuffer

```
#include "VulkanBuffer.h"

#include "VulkanCommandPool.h"
#include "Vertex.h"
#include <iostream>

void swap(VulkanBuffer &lhs, VulkanBuffer &rhs)
{
    std::swap(lhs.logicalDevice_, rhs.logicalDevice_);
    std::swap(lhs.buffer_, rhs.buffer_);
    std::swap(lhs.createInfo_, rhs.createInfo_);
}

VulkanBuffer::VulkanBuffer()
    : buffer_(VK_NULL_HANDLE)
{}

/// \param logicalDevice        Vulkan device
/// \param deviceSizeInbytes    number of bytes of the vertices to be stored in this vertex buffer
/// \param bufferUsageFlags     what will the buffer be used for, eg VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT
/// \param sharingMode          is the buffer used by more than one queue family, eg: VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE, VK_SHARING_MODE_CONCURRENT
VulkanBuffer::VulkanBuffer(const std::shared_ptr<VulkanLogicalDevice>& logicalDevice, VkDeviceSize deviceSizeInbytes, VkBufferUsageFlags bufferUsageFlags, VkSharingMode sharingMode)
    : logicalDevice_(logicalDevice), buffer_(VK_NULL_HANDLE)
{
    createInfo_.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
    createInfo_.size = deviceSizeInbytes;
    createInfo_.usage = bufferUsageFlags; // indicates this data is for a vertex buffer.
    createInfo_.sharingMode = sharingMode; // ownership by one queue family or multiple

    if (vkCreateBuffer(logicalDevice->handle(), &createInfo_, nullptr, &buffer_) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create buffer!");
    }
}

VulkanBuffer::~VulkanBuffer()
{
    if (buffer_ != VK_NULL_HANDLE)
        vkDestroyBuffer(logicalDevice_->handle(), buffer_, nullptr);
}

VulkanBuffer & VulkanBuffer::operator=(VulkanBuffer &&rhs)
{
    swap(*this, rhs);
    return *this;
}

void VulkanBuffer::copyDataFrom(const VulkanBuffer & rhs, const VulkanCommandPool &commandPool, VkDeviceSize dataSizeInBytes)
{
    if (buffer_ == VK_NULL_HANDLE || rhs.buffer_ == VK_NULL_HANDLE)
    {
        std::cout << "Illegal VulkanBuffer::copyDataFrom(), one or more buffers not initialized.\n";
        return;
    }

    VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo allocInfo = {};
    allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    allocInfo.level = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
    allocInfo.commandPool = commandPool.handle();
    allocInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;

    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer;
    vkAllocateCommandBuffers(logicalDevice_->handle(), &allocInfo, &commandBuffer);

    VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo = {};
    beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
    beginInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT;

    vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo);

    VkBufferCopy copyRegion = {};
    copyRegion.size = dataSizeInBytes;
    vkCmdCopyBuffer(commandBuffer, rhs.handle(), buffer_, 1, &copyRegion);

    vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
    submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffer;

    vkQueueSubmit(logicalDevice_->getGraphicsQueue(), 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
    vkQueueWaitIdle(logicalDevice_->getGraphicsQueue());

    vkFreeCommandBuffers(logicalDevice_->handle(), commandPool.handle(), 1, &commandBuffer);

}
```

edit: added this as part of Jherico's suggestion:
When the class crashes, the following is printed from the class functions:

```
handle: 0000000000000000 VulkanBuffer: default ctor()
handle: 0000000000000000 VulkanBuffer: non default ctor() start
handle: 000001B2A00C84E0 VulkanBuffer: non default ctor() end
handle: 0000000000000000 VulkanBuffer: non default ctor() start
```

when it does not crash, the following is printed

```
handle: 0000000000000000 VulkanBuffer: default ctor()
handle: 0000000000000000 VulkanBuffer: non default ctor() start
handle: 000001989ADB56E0 VulkanBuffer: non default ctor() end
handle: 0000000000000000 VulkanBuffer: non default ctor() start
handle: 000001989ADB6310 VulkanBuffer: non default ctor() end
handle: 0000000000000000 VulkanBuffer: operator=()
handle lhs: 0000000000000000 handle rhs: 000001989ADB6310 VulkanBuffer: Swap() start
handle lhs: 000001989ADB6310 handle rhs: 0000000000000000 VulkanBuffer: Swap() end
handle: 000001989ADB6310 VulkanBuffer: copyDataFrom()
handle: 0000000000000000 VulkanBuffer: dtor() // instruction re-ordered here?
handle: 000001989ADB56E0 VulkanBuffer: dtor()
```

Comment: What is in the call stack contents after the crash? Does the crash happen if you comment out `vkCreateBuffer(...)` in the constructor? Does it happen if you comment out some of `std::swap`s in `swap(VulkanBuffer&, VulkanBuffer&)`?

Comment: in C++, you may use `rvalue` instead of `r-value` ?

Comment: @Evg it crashes in Vkcreatebuffer(), commenting that out will prevent the crash. The crash occurs after entering vkcreatebuffer, before the move assignment or swap() functions are called. It only happens in debug mode

Comment: It seems strange to `= delete` move construction but not move assignment

Comment: @rafix after swapping all elements, both rhs and lhs -are- valid. If I just set rhs to null, there will be a memory leak as the value in rhs (originally in lhs) will not be released when the destructor is called on rhs.

Comment: @rafix07 they dont have the same value before or after the swap... eg if: before: lhs.buffer_ = 1, rhs.buffer_ = 2. after: lhs.buffer_ = 2, rhs.buffer_ = 1. They only time they can be the same is if they are both null before the move

Comment: @aCuria so implementation of `VulkanBuffer & operator=(VulkanBuffer &&rhs);` is incorrect, [1] release resources which are kept by *this object, [2] move resources from `rhs` to *this [3] leave `rhs` with valid state - clear its members to null.

Comment: @rafix07 you have not explained why using the swap idiom to implement move assignment is incorrect. Usually it is implemented as both the move assignment and assignment as one function: foo& operator=(foo other){ swap(*this, other); } but here I want to explicitly NOT have a copy constructor so the signature is foo& operator=(foo && other)

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very helpful.

Comment: Where do you zero-initialize the `VulkanBuffer::createInfo_`?

Comment: @krOoze, I do not zero-initialize createInfo_, it does not appear to be necessary

Comment: @aCuria What do you mean "not appear to be necessary"? If left unitialized e.g. `pNext` can be garbage, and the driver can crash trying to dereference it.

Comment: In your Q you are saying the crash happens in your non-default constructor, but the printout seems to say it completed successfully. So where exactly does it crash??

Comment: @krOoze, you are right, this indeed was the issue,  this struct was not zero initialized properly, and depending on what was in memory the non default constructor will complete successfully (or not)

Comment: @aCuria Great! I will formally submit an Answer then...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have forgoten to fully initialize the `VkBufferCreateInfo` (i.e. `createInfo_`).

You only seem to partially initialize here:

```
createInfo_.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
createInfo_.size = deviceSizeInbytes;
createInfo_.usage = bufferUsageFlags; // indicates this data is for a vertex buffer.
createInfo_.sharingMode = sharingMode; // ownership by one queue family or multiple
```

That leaves these members uninitialized: `pNext`, `flags`, `queueFamilyIndexCount` and `pQueueFamilyIndices`. Notably if `pNext` happens to be non-`NULL`, the driver **will** try to dereference it (and crash because the pointer points nowhere).

This is the first kind of bugs you should be thinking of if something happens only in a Debug profile. In Release profile 99 % of the time uninitialized variable will be zero. The compiler does help you here and in Debug profile it fills uninitialized memory with (non-zero) garbage, so it crashes for you in order to discover an otherwisely hidden bug.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that you've got some sort of double-destruction of a buffer going on.  You should have validation layers enabled while developing, because if you do so, they validation should catch this before it triggers a crash.

In terms of figuring out what exactly is going wrong, the easiest way is probably to put logging in your move assignment operator, ctor and dtor (which includes the handle of the buffer being passed to `vkDestroyBuffer`) so that you can see what the actual sequence of calls is.

Comment: my validation layer is strangely silent, I have added the call sequences

Comment: doesn't appear to be any double destruction going on. Only the default constructor and constructor are called before the crash occurs in debug mode.